# passing a closure to addTarget in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a method that gets movies from an api and then loads the data into the UITableView.  I want to reuse the network calls for a refresh control and at the end of the http get request, to call a completion handler that basically stops the refresh control once it's successful.  Is that possible?

```
func getMovies(completion: (() -> ())?) {
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    Alamofire.request("https://api.moviesite").responseJSON {
        response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let data):
            if let json = data as? NSDictionary {
                self.movieResults = json["results"] as! [NSDictionary]
                self.nowPlayingTableView.reloadData()
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            self.showNetworkError(show: true)
        }

        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        if completion != nil {
            completion!()
        }
    }
}
```

And when I use this method in viewDidLoad, I'd like to do something like this:

```
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(NowPlayingViewController.getMovies(refreshControl.endRefreshing)), for: .valueChanged)
        nowPlayingTableView.insertSubview(refreshControl, at: 0)
```

but I get a compiler error about

getMovies cannot be used, did you mean to use a value type instead?

Comment: Why dont just stop the `refreshControl` in the `getMovies` completion block? you can send along the `sender` which is the `refreshControl` itself

Comment: @Tj3n can you provide syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only `selector` that you set with `UIRefreshControl` is `#selector(refreshing)` or `#selector(refreshing(_:))` means `selector` either with `UIRefreshControl` as parameter or without any parameter. If you want to end​ the refreshing then try like this.

```
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshing(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
nowPlayingTableView.insertSubview(refreshControl, at: 0)
```

Now add one action `refreshing` with your controller and call `getMovies` with it and in completion of your getMovies call the `end​Refreshing` on `UIRefreshControl`

```
func refreshing(_ sender: UIRefreshControl) {
    self.getMovies() {
        sender.end​Refreshing()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `refreshControl` code to:

```
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(NowPlayingViewController.getMovies(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

And your function

```
func getMovies(_ sender: UIRefreshControl) {
   ...
   sender.endRefreshing()
}
```